# How to use a callback to add to a string stored in a Div using Dash in Python?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using dash in Python to create a dashboard. I'd like to update a string stored in a Div each time a new string is generated as part of another Dashboard element/process. My best attempt to create a callback for this so far is unsuccessful but is intended to work by:

1. Taking the `new_string` as input.
2. Adding it to the `output_div`.
3. Adding further `new_string`'s to string data already collected in `output_div` given by it's `state`.

Here's the callback code:

```
@Dashboard.callback(
                    Output('output_div', 'children'),
                    [Input('new_string', 'children')],
                    [State('output_div', 'children')]
                   )
def create_complete_string(new_string, string_in_output_div_so_far):
    if string_in_output_div_so_far is None:
       return new_string
    else:
       return string_in_output_div_so_far + new_string
```

This does not work as hoped as it only outputs one instance of `new_string` (the last one of many generated) in `output_div` rather all of them joined together.

Could anyone suggest what I have done wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

With the given code snippet it's hard to figure out the error, it will be good if you can paste a minimal [reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a snippet; But rather here is a minimal working code that caters;

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
            dcc.Input(id="text"),
            html.Div(id='new_string'),
            html.Div(id='output_div'),
    ])


@app.callback(
            Output('new_string', 'children'),
            [Input('text', 'value')]
        )
def output_text(text):
    return text
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved it. I got the basic concept working after considering the comments made by @Lawliet. Heres the code, which adds onto a string after more input is made.

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

Dashboard = dash.Dash(__name__)
server    = Dashboard.server
Dashboard.layout = html.Div([                                
                             dcc.Input(id='new_string'),
                             html.Div(id='other_div'),
                             html.Div(id='output_div'),
                           ])

@Dashboard.callback(
                    Output('other_div', 'children'),
                    [Input('new_string', 'value')]
                   )
def output_string(new_string):
        return new_string

@Dashboard.callback(
                    Output('output_div', 'children'),
                    [Input('other_div' , 'children')],
                    [State('output_div', 'children')]
                   )
def create_complete_string(other_div_children, string_in_output_div_so_far):
    if string_in_output_div_so_far is None:
        return other_div_children
    else:
        return string_in_output_div_so_far + other_div_children

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Dashboard.run_server(debug=True)
```